# Preciso inserir nº de telefone e nº de celular na mesma textbox usando máscaras em Windows form C#

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio

Tipo eu queria saber se tem alguma forma de criar um formato sempre que o usuário digitar um tanto de caracteres (ex: 8 para telefone e 9 para celular), já identificar e aplicar no textbox.
Ou quando o usuário digitar um caractere específico já identificar que é o nº de telefone ou celular (ex: quando inserir o nº 9 já identificar e aplicar o formato para celular).
Ou alguma outra maneira de aplicar os 2 em um único textbox.

segue abaixo um código que eu fiz para telefone caso ele seja útil.

```
private void Tel(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
        {
            if (char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar) || e.KeyChar == (char)(Keys.Back))
            {
                e.Handled = false;                
                if (e.KeyChar == (char)(Keys.Back))
                {
                    txtTel.Text = "";
                }
                if (txtTel.Text.Length == 0)
                {
                    txtTel.Text += "(";
                }

                if (txtTel.Text.Length == 6)
                {
                    txtTel.Text += ")";
                }

                if (txtTel.Text.Length == 2)
                {
                    txtTel.Text += "X";
                }

                if (txtTel.Text.Length == 3)
                {
                    txtTel.Text += "X";
                }

               if (txtTel.Text.Length == 11)
                {
                    txtTel.Text += "-";
                }
            }

            else
            {
                e.Handled = true;
            }
            txtTel.SelectionStart = txtTel.TextLength + 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

A melhor opção é usar um controle do tipo **MaskedTextBox** ao invés do **TextBox**. Ele já irá incluir a máscara no formato de telefone por exemplo (XX) XXXX-XXXX.

Após alterar o controle para MaskedTextBox, adicione um manipulador de eventos para TextChanged nele:

```cs
private void maskedTextBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if ("9".Equals(maskedTextBox1.Text.Substring(5, 1)))
    {
        maskedTextBox1.Mask = "(99) 99999-9999";
    }
    else
    {
        maskedTextBox1.Mask = "(99) 9999-9999";
    }
}
```

No meu exemplo, apenas inclui uma lógica de acrescentar 1 dígito quando depois do DDD vier um número 9.

caso queira fazer alguma ação quando a máscara for rejeitada, adicione um manipulador de eventos para o evento MaskInputRejected. Veja que no meu caso, eu limpo o campo caso a máscara seja preenchida incorretamente.

```cs
private void maskedTextBox1_MaskInputRejected(object sender, MaskInputRejectedEventArgs e)
{
    if (maskedTextBox1.Text.Length != maskedTextBox1.Mask.Length)
        maskedTextBox1.ResetText();
}
```